# How to show that an algebra is contained in a clone

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations, universal-algebra

**My question:**

If we have a be the binary operation on 2 = {0, 1}, denoted $\overline{\land}$, defined by

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\overline{\land} &0 & 1  \\ \hline
 0&1 & 0\\ 
\hline
1 &  0 &0 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}

How do I prove that $\mathcal{A}$ = {¬, ∧, ∨} ⊆ $\mathcal{C}$ = Clo($(2, \overline{\land})$)?

**My thoughts:**

The $\mathcal{A}$ is probably some lattice, however, I am confused about what should be the universe here. I understand the operations {¬, ∧, ∨} as inverse, meet and join respectively.

The $\mathcal{C}$ is the clone of term operations. The clone $\mathcal{C}$ on $(2, \overline{\land})$ should be defined a set of operations on $(2, \overline{\land})$ which contains all projections and is closed under
composition of functions.

So I think maybe I should just show that any two elements that give 0 or 1 after applying the operations from $\mathcal{A}$ have to automatically give 0 or 1 after applying the operation $\overline{\land}$? But I am not very sure how would I show that if this was the correct process.

**Why I am interested in this:**

We were assigned this as an exercise in our university course and I am following mostly the book *Universal Algebra: Fundamentals and Selected Topics* by Clifford Bergman. In the book, there is only similar exercise (4.10.4 in particular), but no solutions.

I would love to learn to work with clones, not only study theorems and proofs, so any advice on this or any learning sources with more exercises are very appreciated.

Comment: It is certainly true that all of AND, OR and NOT can be 'made' by projections and compositions of the NAND operator (the thing that defines your algebra). You can check this directly. E.g. NOT(X) is the same as X AND X; X OR Y = NOT(X NAND Y) and hence equal to (X NAND Y) NAND (X NAND Y) etc. I am however not sure if I understand the definition of clone well enough to conclude that these constructions together form the answer to your question. (I think they do)

Comment: All in all, having a single operator (NAND) that all by itself 'generates' all the other, more famous operators is a rather spectacular and surprising observation, I think. So I can imagine that the book makes an exercise about it (even if the wording obscures the simplicity of the phenomenon)

Comment: The unary operation $\neg$ (not), and the binary operations $\wedge$ (and), $\vee$ (or) are meant to be operations defined on $\{0,1\}$. You need to know their definitions/tables to solve the problem. Once you know the tables, you can figure out how to generate those operations with $\overline{\land}$. To get started, check that $\neg x = (x\overline{\land} x)$.

Comment: @Vincent  thank you for the comments! If you dont want to post an answer, I maybe use your advice later and try to create my own answer to this question.

Comment: @Vincent What do you mean by "NOT(X) is the same as X AND X"? The AND is binary operation, but NOT is unary operation, no?

Comment: @Tererza Sorry the X AND X was a typo. Not(X) is the same as X NAND X (with an extra N). You turn the binary operator NAND into a unary one by 'promising' to only feed the same element into both inputs

Comment: @Vincent So in general, if the AND, OR, NOT operations are all somehow "created" by the NAND operation, this is sufficient reason to say that they are in the clone? (Sound suspiciously easy to me).

Comment: Hm yes this is why I typed a comment instead of an answer. The fact that the AND, OR, NOT operations are all somehow "created" by the NAND operation is interesting and surprising and worth making an exercise in a book about ESPECIALLY since it is sort of 'common knowledge' that 'all' operations can in turn be created from these three. But if it is also enough to say that they are in the clone depends on the precise definition of clone, with which I am not familiar with, so I dare not say.

Comment: @Vincent Hmm, that is interesting, yes. I just use the definition "clone = projections &compositions" so it should be okay, since NOT is projection of NAND etc. But how is AND generated from the other operations tho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I got some nice advice in the comments (thank you!), I will try to post an answer myself. Feel free to add anything.

A clone $\mathcal{C}$ is a set of operations on $(2, \overline{\land})$ which contains all projections and is closed under composition of functions.

Denote $\mathcal{A} = (\{0, 1\}, \overline{\land})$.

The unary operation $\neg$ ("not"), and the binary operations $\land$ ("and"), $\lor$ ("or") are operations defined on $\{0,1 \}$. We need to know how the operations $\neg, \land$ and $\lor$ behave to solve the problem. We create Cayley tables to observe how the operations can be generated from one another.

We will show that that all $\neg, \land$ and $\lor$ can be created by projections and compositions of the $\overline{\land}$ operator.

**Proof that $\neg \in \mathcal{C}$**

The $\neg$ operator is unary operator and therefore the Cayley table has outputs only for $(x,x)$.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\neg &0 & 1  \\ \hline
 0& 1 & -\\ 
\hline
1 &  - & 0 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$

Observe that $\neg(x,x)$ is the same $x \overline{\land} x$. The $\neg(x,x)$ operator is like the $\overline{\land}$ operator restricted only to one variable instead of two. Hence, $\neg(x,x)$ is a part of the $\mathcal{C} = Clo((2, \overline{\land}))$

**Proof that $\land \in \mathcal{C}$**

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\land &0 & 1  \\ \hline
 0& 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
1 &  0 &1 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$

First, I will generate $\land$ from $\lor$ and $\neg$. Then I will express $\lor$ and $\neg$ using $\overline{\land}$ and we are done.

Observe $\neg x \lor \neg y$.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\neg x \lor \neg y &0 & 1  \\ \hline
 0& 1 & 1\\ 
\hline
1 &  1 &0 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$

Then, observe that the table above is just negation of the $\land$ operator. Therefore  $\land = \neg (\neg x \lor \neg y)$.

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\neg (\neg x \lor \neg y) &0 & 1  \\ \hline
 0& 0 & 0\\ 
\hline
1 &  0 &1 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$

Since we have already shown that the $\lor$ and $\neg$ operators are in $Clo((2, \overline{\land}))$, it means $\land$ is also in the clone, because it can be created from these operators and therefore from the $\overline{\land}$ operator.

**Proof that $\lor \in \mathcal{C}$**

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\lor &0 & 1  \\ \hline
 0& 0 & 1\\ 
\hline
1 &  1 &1 \\ 
\hline
\end{array}$

Observe that
$x \lor y = \neg(x \overline{\land} y)$ and hence equal to $(x \overline{\land} y) \overline{\land} (x \overline{\land} y)$. It means that it can be made as a composition of $ \overline{\land}$ operators, so it belongs to $\mathcal{C} = Clo((2, \overline{\land}))$.

Comment: My tip for creating AND from NAND is first create it from NOT and OR and then translate that expression to NANDs and then simplify

Comment: @Vincent Thank you! :) Got it